# log4net AdoNetAppender failing for messages > 2000 char

Tags: oracle10g, log4net

I am facing a trouble with an AdoNetAppender. Things work fine for messages upto 2000 chars length. Everything falls apart if the message(PI_S_MESSAGE) is > 2000 chars. My database is Oracle 10g and shown below is the appender config. Connect string is injected on the fly, when initializing the appender.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><log4net>
<appender name="MyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="0" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />      
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE(Datetime,Log_Level,userid,Message,machine) VALUES (:PI_D_DATE, :PI_S_LEVEL, :PI_S_USERID, :PI_S_MESSAGE, :PI_S_MACHINE)" />      
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_D_DATE" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>     
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_S_LEVEL" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>     
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_S_USERID" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%u" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_S_MESSAGE" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_S_MACHINE" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="All"/>
  <appender-ref ref="MyAppender"/>
</root>
```

When debug mode is enabled, it pumps out an oracle error

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Exception while writing to database
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: I think this is an error in the Microsoft .NET Provider for Oracle. I explained what I found out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156019/ora-01461-can-bind-a-long-value-only-for-insert-into-a-long-column-occurs-when/29637314#29637314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing the `dbType` attribute for the `PI_S_MESSAGE` parameter to `AnsiString`.
Perhaps it was trying an `nvarchar` binding when used with a dbType as `String`.

Eventhough unrelated, this thread saved my arse. 
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2369841

New config follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><log4net>
<appender name="MyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="0" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />      
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE(Datetime,Log_Level,userid,Message,machine) VALUES (:PI_D_DATE, :PI_S_LEVEL, :PI_S_USERID, :PI_S_MESSAGE, :PI_S_MACHINE)" />      
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_D_DATE" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>     
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_S_LEVEL" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>     
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_S_USERID" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%u" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_S_MESSAGE" />
    <dbType value="AnsiString" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value=":PI_S_MACHINE" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="All"/>
  <appender-ref ref="MyAppender"/>
</root>
```