# Ignite CacheJdbcPojoStore encounter error when using clob datatype

Tags: ignite

Would appreciate your help greatly~

I have a DB field that is of CLOB datatype. Originally we used String in POJO and it managed to store data into DB with the following JdbcTypeField

```java
new JdbcTypeField(Types.CLOB, "VALUE_X", String.class, "valueX")
```

However, we encounter a problem when inserting bigger data. 
[ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column-Occurs when querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156019/ora-01461-can-bind-a-long-value-only-for-insert-into-a-long-column-occurs-when)

Now that we tried to change our variable to Clob with the following setting:

```java
new JdbcTypeField(Types.CLOB, "VALUE_X", Clob.class, "valueX"),
```

However, we encountered the following error, any idea on this error?

```java
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to marshal 
object with optimized marshaller: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1c70676
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:186) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:147) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:134) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:496) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1160) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:663) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:793) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:206) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:147) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:134) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:496) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1160) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:663) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:793) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:206) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:147) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:134) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:496) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1160) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:663) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:793) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:206) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:147) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:134) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:496) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1160) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:663) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:793) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:206) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:147) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:134) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:496) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryBuilderSerializer.writeValue(BinaryBuilderSerializer.java:207) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryValueWithType.writeTo(BinaryValueWithType.java:48) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryBuilderSerializer.writeValue(BinaryBuilderSerializer.java:73) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryBuilderSerializer.writeValue(BinaryBuilderSerializer.java:54) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.serializeTo(BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.java:313) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.build(BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.java:183) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStore.buildBinaryObject(CacheJdbcPojoStore.java:252) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStore.buildObject(CacheJdbcPojoStore.java:136) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore$1.call(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:467) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore$1.call(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:434) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to serialize object: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1c70676
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.marshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:206) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.marshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:58) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.marshal(IgniteUtils.java:9815) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:179) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeSerializable(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:324) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.write(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:827) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:224) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeFields(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:516) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeSerializable(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:328) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.write(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:827) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:224) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeFields(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:516) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeSerializable(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:328) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.write(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:827) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:224) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:152) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.marshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:201) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at oracle.jdbc.internal.OpaqueString.writeObject(OpaqueString.java:93) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeSerializable(OptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:318) ~[ignite-core-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Comment: First CLOB isn't supported type by ignite. Second: Failed to serialize object: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection. Looks like you tried to put T4CConnection into the cache, is it correct?

Comment: Could you share with me where you access the info to state what it supports and what it do not? I also suspected it do not support. I did not try to put T4CConnection into cache, it was handled by CacheJdbcPojoStore for loadCache operation.

Comment: Could you please share your code, some small reproducer like a pom based project? For now, I can say that try to serialize T4CConnection, the exception explicitly says this.

Comment: Same error in 2021. Any new solutions?