# CLOB deserialization is not handled in ignite persistence

Tags: java, ignite

we have setup ignite persistence and it is working fine until we found that it is throwing issues for clob related datatypes. is there a work around other than writing custom store just for one datatype?

we wrote custom jdbc store for loading, writing and deleting. however there are few options missed in the custom store we wrote from the framework ignite has provided. so we wanted to check if there is a simple work around to handle clob datatypes

Comment: What issues is it throwing?

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are large, then tuning the pagesize could be an option
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/large-objects

Comment: Thanks for responding, but it is not the performance issue in loading, it is not able to deserialize clob datatype to string. "failed to serialize or deserialize"

Comment: Can you give more context. Are you reading from DB and trying to store in ignite or vice versa? Can you give a link to the full log snippet?
Does this relate to your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085807/ignite-cachejdbcpojostore-encounter-error-when-using-clob-datatype

Comment: am trying both ways which i had both read and write through enabled