# CLOB : ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, clob, ojdbc

I am getting this error for Clob datatype in table. The String content I am trying to store as clob is more than 4K for sure (around 190KB). 
I am using JPA in spring app.

Consider responseObj is a JSONObject with 190K of data.

```
Clob errorResponse = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob(responseObj.toString().toCharArray());                 
errorResponse.setString(1L,responseObj.toString());

int rowsInserted = errorRepository.insertEfileErrorLogRequest(responseObj.getString("key"), Short.parseShort(year), errorResponse);
```

ErrorRepository.insertErrorLogRequest()

```
    @Modifying
@Query(value="INSERT INTO ERRORLOG " +
        "(KEY,YEAR,ERROR_CLOB,TIMESTAMP) " +
        "VALUES " +
        "(?1,?2,
        "TO_CLOB(?3),SYSTIMESTAMP)",nativeQuery = true)
int insertErrorLogRequest(String key, short year, Clob errorResponse) throws SQLException, DataAccessException;
```

There is no long column in the database table. 
I am getting **ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column**

I am using 
Oracle 11g &
ojdbc14 maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156019/ora-01461-can-bind-a-long-value-only-for-insert-into-a-long-column-occurs-when

Comment: Pls show the DDL of the `ERRORLOG` table. What ist the DATATYPE of `ERROR_CLOB`?

Comment: I would upgrade the driver to 11g (11.2.0.4).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber : Datatype of ERROR_CLOB is CLOB.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene : I have upgraded the driver to  <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
But still same error.

Comment: Can you please upgrade to 11.2.0.3 or 11.2.0.4?

Comment: @JeandeLavarene : Same Error with 11.2.0.3 and 11.2.0.4.

Comment: This would have worked with Oracle 12c where the limit of a VARCHAR is 32k and the driver would have been able to send your error message as a VARCHAR directly. In your case the driver is trying to send the data as a LONG because it's larger than 4k. A simple option is to use the LONG type instead of CLOB for your ERROR_CLOB column.